# installing fujitsu drivers on u1010

Tags: 13.04, fujitsu-siemens

I'm running Ubuntu/Lubuntu 13.04 on a fujitsu u1010.  The installation went well but I ran into trouble when trying to install drivers following instructions on https://katastrophos.net/andre/blog/2012/05/29/installing-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-on-fujitsu-u820-u2010-u2020/

I'm a newbie to Linux, so I don't know how to interpret the screen output but I saw whole bunch of 'error' and I guess there is something wrong, please help.  Thanks.

Details as follow:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src'
Making all in linux
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src/linux'
make -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-30-generic/build M=/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src/linux modules
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src/linux/fujitsu-tablet.o
/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src/linux/fujitsu-tablet.c:200:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘input_fujitsu_setup’
/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src/linux/fujitsu-tablet.c:289:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘fujitsu_dmi_matched’
/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src/linux/fujitsu-tablet.c:299:15: error: ‘fujitsu_dmi_matched’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src/linux/fujitsu-tablet.c:364:30: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘fujitsu_walk_resources’
/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src/linux/fujitsu-tablet.c:387:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘acpi_fujitsu_add’
/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src/linux/fujitsu-tablet.c:425:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘acpi_fujitsu_remove’
/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src/linux/fujitsu-tablet.c:444:13: error: ‘acpi_fujitsu_add’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src/linux/fujitsu-tablet.c:444:3: error: initializer element is not constant
/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src/linux/fujitsu-tablet.c:444:3: error: (near initialization for ‘acpi_fujitsu_driver.ops.add’)
/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src/linux/fujitsu-tablet.c:445:13: error: ‘acpi_fujitsu_remove’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src/linux/fujitsu-tablet.c:445:3: error: initializer element is not constant
/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src/linux/fujitsu-tablet.c:445:3: error: (near initialization for ‘acpi_fujitsu_driver.ops.remove’)
/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src/linux/fujitsu-tablet.c:446:3: error: unknown field ‘resume’ specified in initializer
/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src/linux/fujitsu-tablet.c:243:13: error: ‘input_fujitsu_remove’ defined but not used [-Werror=unused-function]
/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src/linux/fujitsu-tablet.c:249:20: error: ‘fujitsu_interrupt’ defined but not used [-Werror=unused-function]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[5]: *** [/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src/linux/fujitsu-tablet.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [_module_/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src/linux] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic'
make[3]: *** [fujitsu-tablet.ko] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src/linux'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/xx/fjbtndrv-2.3.2'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not need it anymore. Atleast in 3.10, `fujitsu-tablet.ko` comes preinstalled. Check the output of `$ lsmod | grep fujitsu`

If output has `fujitsu-tablet`, then it's already installed.

If you want to build it anyways, download fixed copy from [this link](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/contrib/linux/drivers/platform/x86/fujitsu-tablet.c).

Replace in the build directory, and build should go fine.

The reason old version is failing is that `__devinit` and `__devexit` are deprecated in newer kernel versions.
The field `remove` (under `struct acpi_driver --> ops`) has also been deprecated.

Comment: Don't really understand what you are trying to explain.  I'm new to Linux but thank you for your effort.